# Debian Duster shuts down after exactly 12 hours

Tags: debian

i am running an server with debian10 to host a shop-website. The server stops after exactly 12 hours and i have to reboot the system. I have checked the following logs:

```
/var/log/sys.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/dmeslog
```

But there is no error at the moment of the shutdown. Hardware has been replaced already, only kept the hard drives. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Unix and Linux stack exchange (one of our sister sites, look on top right icon) is the best place for such questions. To me, it seems a configuration (e.g. to power off if one forget to explicit do it), of your kiosk part. It should not be related to Debian base installation or packages.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thank you, i added the question on unix stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can see when your system shutdowns using

```
last -xwF reboot
```

or

```
last -xwF shutdown
```

If the system is using **systemd** here is a possibility to see at least if there is a shutdown sequence running :

```
/bin/systemctl list-jobs shutdown.target
```

or :

```
/bin/systemctl  is-active shutdown.target
```

> root@duster:~# /bin/systemctl list-jobs  shutdown.target
> **No jobs running.**

but if the shutdown was initiated directly with `sudo shutdown 43200 --no wall` then you will see nothing, and the only solution is to enter `shutdown -c` to stop the shutdown sequence.
If you enter `shutdown -c` when there is no sequence is running , nothing happens.

So the temporary solution would be to enter a crontab that sends `shutdown -c` every hour for example. This at least stops the server from shutting down if there was a shutdown sequence.

You can also try to grep all logs for the word "shutdown"

```
find /var/log -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "shutdown"
```

I wish you good luck !

Comment: thank you. those commands just showed our own orderly shutdowns, which makes us think, that the server maybe isnt shutting down, but the network causes an issue.
the provider added a KVM console for us - i will check if there is still a terminal visible when the server is not responding which will be an evidence for not shutting down, but having a network issue